# How to call a C# library function with ref and out parameter from python?

Tags: python, .net, ref, python.net, pythonnet

I use pythonnet not ironpython.

There is a function like this:

```
test(ref string p1,out string p2)
```

How can I call `test` in python 3.6?

```
import clr
import sys
import System
sys.path.append(r'd:\dll')  
clr.FindAssembly('communication.dll')  
from  communication import *  
dll=IEC62056()
dll.test(----------)
```

Comment: you can check similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998687/calling-a-net-function-in-python-which-has-a-reference-parameter)

Comment: hmm not a best solution but why not make a console program to wrap your dll and then call console program from python ?

Comment: @Rahul Agarwal this page is iropython not pythonnet https://pythonnet.github.io/

Comment: @ Agent_Orange  I am sorry, i can't understand, can you show me examples?

Answer (score 1):

I can't test the code without communication.dll, so please check if the following code is working for you:

```
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append("D:\\dll") # path to dll
clr.AddReference("communication") # add reference to communication.dll
from  communication import test

ref_string_p1 = "----------"
out_string_p2 = test(ref_string_p1)
print(out_string_p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can feed ref as a regular argument, and feed out arbitrarily. pythonnet will return them positionally as tuple.

assume `void test(ref string p1,out string p2)` in c#,
you get `p1, p2 = test(p1, None)` in python