# Calling C# DLL from Python with "out" parameter

Tags: python, c#

I have a C# piece that generates a DLL which I'm trying to invoke from Python. The C# prototype is as follow:

```
public Main(NationalInstruments.TestStand.Interop.API.SequenceContext sequenceContext){
    public void ShowFullOptions(out bool errorOccurred, out int errorCode, out String errorMsg) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998687/calling-a-net-function-in-python-which-has-a-reference-parameter) which explains how to achieve to pass "out" parameters from python, without success since clr.Reference does not exist and throw me the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'Reference'
```

I have pythonnet installed, version 2.3.

My python code:

```
import clr

dll_path = R"thatDllPath.dll"
clr.AddReference(dll_path)

from Flamenco_Calibration_Interface import Main
import System

my_instance = Main(None)
v1 = clr.Reference[System.Boolean](False)
v2 = clr.Reference[System.Int64](1)
v3 = clr.Reference[System.String]("")

a = my_instance.ShowFullOptions(v1,v2,v3)
```

I have checked that the DLL path is good and I am able to successfully call the C# method if I overload "ShowFullOptions" with a version without any arguments.
The main problem resides in that I have the "out" keyword in the C# method prototype.

How do you properly generate argument in python so they are accepted as "out" within C# ?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: yes? what is the question?

Comment: python + net. you can give a try to: https://ironpython.net/

Comment: A main function has to be compatible with the windows operating system and needs a parameter list Main(string[] args).  arg[0] windows will assign the name of the program and the parameters are strings like in a command line.  You can also pass data through standard input and standard output.

Comment: I cannot change the prototype since that C# piece was originally designed to be called from within TestStand (LabView world). Although the main prototype is not as you say I managed to call it using None as unique argument.